# How to load images used in a custom control?

Tags: c#, image, visual-studio-2012, bitmap, custom-controls

I am creating a custom control, a media player tool for C# Windows forms.

My control has custom images for the standard buttons (e.g., play, pause, stop, next, previous, random).  My problem is that I can't load these images correctly.  Since I'm doing this in the control's constructor, it fails during design time when I drag the control from the toolbox and drop it onto a form.

It works fine when I load images using the full path to the actual file

```
Image bmpPlay = Image.FromFile(@"C:\Users\CybeX\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\WindowsFormsApplication3\WindowsFormsApplication3\bin\Debug\images\play.bmp");
```

But I don't want to do this as, obviously, the paths will be different depending on where the application is installed.  I tried using relative paths

```
Image bmpPause = Image.FromFile(@"Images\pause.bmp");
```

but this throws an exception, saying that it cannot find the file specified.

I tried copying these images to the debug folder for the application but gives the same error.

How can I create these images during runtime in a way that will work reliably no matter where the application is installed?

For completeness, here's the code for my control.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.IO;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication3
{
    public partial class mediaplayerbox : System.Windows.Forms.Button
    {    
        const int buttonwidth = 150;
        const int buttonheight = 150;        

        public mediaplayerbox()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            Button btnPlay = new Button();
            Button btnPause = new Button();
            Button btnStop = new Button();
            Button btnNext = new Button();
            Button btnPrevious = new Button();
            Button btnPlayRandom = new Button();

            btnPlay.SetBounds(0, 0, buttonwidth, buttonheight);
            btnPause.SetBounds(btnPlay.Left + buttonwidth, 0, buttonwidth, buttonheight);
            btnStop.SetBounds(btnPause.Left + buttonwidth, 0, buttonwidth, buttonheight);
            btnNext.SetBounds(btnStop.Left + buttonwidth, 0, buttonwidth, buttonheight);
            btnPrevious.SetBounds(btnNext.Left + buttonwidth, 0, buttonwidth, buttonheight);
            btnPlayRandom.SetBounds(btnPrevious.Left + buttonwidth, 0, buttonwidth, buttonheight);

            Image bmpPlay = Image.FromFile(@"C:\Users\CybeX\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\WindowsFormsApplication3\WindowsFormsApplication3\bin\Debug\images\play.bmp");
            Image bmpPause = Image.FromFile(@"Images\pause.bmp");
            Image bmpStop = Image.FromFile(@"Images\stop.bmp");
            Image bmpNext = Image.FromFile(@"Images\next.bmp");
            Image bmpPrevious = Image.FromFile(@"Images\previous.bmp");
            Image bmpPlayRandom = Image.FromFile(@"Images\play_random.bmp");

            btnPlay.Image = bmpPlay;
            btnPause.Image = bmpPause;
            btnStop.Image = bmpStop;
            btnPrevious.Image = bmpNext;
            btnNext.Image = bmpPrevious;
            btnPlayRandom.Image = bmpPlayRandom;

            btnPlay.ImageAlign = ContentAlignment.MiddleCenter;
            btnPause.ImageAlign = ContentAlignment.MiddleCenter;
            btnStop.ImageAlign = ContentAlignment.MiddleCenter;
            btnNext.ImageAlign = ContentAlignment.MiddleCenter;
            btnPrevious.ImageAlign = ContentAlignment.MiddleCenter;
            btnPlayRandom.ImageAlign = ContentAlignment.MiddleCenter;

            btnPlay.FlatStyle = FlatStyle.Flat;
            btnPlay.FlatStyle = FlatStyle.Flat;
            btnPlay.FlatStyle = FlatStyle.Flat;
            btnNext.FlatStyle = FlatStyle.Flat;
            btnPrevious.FlatStyle = FlatStyle.Flat;
            btnPlayRandom.FlatStyle = FlatStyle.Flat;    
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: your error message is telling you exactly what the problem is ..so why don't you provide the actual Path of the Images.. for example create an entry in your app.config file that has the file path this seems to be very straight forward

Comment: that is exactly what I do not want, that means hard coding the exact file path, how else am I able to create this control by suing buttons ina  subfolder called images, the add this to a toolbox where it wont give me this error,clearly I am not seeing it, but thanks for your response, I apprciate some help,after all thats what I asked the question for, not for downvotes and no help

Comment: have you heard of a resource file..? do a google search on how to use it in C#

Comment: @MethodMan Thank you for you suggestion, I do not mean to come accross as disrespectful, but if you make a suggest, just give a reason why u suggest this, I am a 2nd year varsity student, and we are still doing fig. console.writeline(), so I do not fully understand these concepts, so if you would be kind enough, just to explain the prob and why you suggest a res.  file, why will that solve the prob?

Comment: let me restate my question in a different way.. when you are creating the console application, do you have an `app.config` file that's part of your project / solution..? if not then I would read up on how to use the `System.COnfiguration Class` within the .config file you can add `key value` pairs and access them using `ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["your key"]` I hope hat this makes sense

Answer (score 0):

Don't use a hardcoded path! Instead, create a resource file an embed the image there, then load it as usually with resources.

Comment: could you please give me an example of how i must do that, I am a 2nd ear varsity student, we are still doing "console.writeline"

Comment: @user253935 Been an student is not enough reason for not knowing how to make a simple search in google... I already gave you the keywords ;-) 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb514517(v=vs.90).aspx

Comment: Don't be dopey.  He's running a Forms app, whereas you linked @cybex to a WPF app resource.  He needs to add the images to his application as strongly typed embedded images, after which he can simply grab them from his Resources namespace.  Here's an answer of mine with details http://stackoverflow.com/a/7970042/1228 there's a specific option for adding them as System.Drawing.Bitmap instances.