# Refrence/add and use files in vb.net executable

Tags: xml, vb.net, embed, exe

I was wondering if I could embed files such as xmls to my executable and still refrence to them in the finished release?

Im ussing VB.net

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/10845457/1070452 ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how can I embed a file into an exe?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7969947/how-can-i-embed-a-file-into-an-exe)